# How to create a delete LINQ command please from the enclosed Delete SQL?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using MVC3, EF4.1, C#.

I have this SQL code which I would like to convert to LINQ, but I am struggling to grasp the correct LINQ for it, so I am reaching out to your Expert LINQ gurus for some help please.

The Delete SQL which is taken from a trigger, is:

```
DELETE FROM Feature 
WHERE NOT EXISTS  
(
SELECT    
LU1 AS LUID 
FROM dbo.CLASS WHERE SectionId = Feature.SectionId AND LU1 = Feature.StdLibraryItemId
UNION 
SELECT    
LU2 AS LUID 
FROM dbo.CLASS WHERE SectionId = Feature.SectionId AND LU2 = Feature.StdLibraryItemId
)
```

Huge thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look something like this in EF (assuming your DbContext is `db`):

```
var featuresToRemove = db.Feature.Where(f => !db.Class.Any(c => c.SectionID == f.SectionID && (c.LU1 == f.StdLibraryItemID || c.LU2 == f.StdLibraryItemID ))
foreach (var feature in featuresToRemove)
{
    db.Feature.Remove(feature);
}
```